# Atualização DNS cpanel

Tags: dns, ip, cpanel

Estou tentando usar um *script* para atualizar o IP de nosso servidor, para poder acessar externamente já que usamos IP dinâmico.

O *script* que uso é [esse][1]:

Mas ele me retorna o seguinte erro :

```
<?php
// Based on the hard work of Mitchel Haan
// https://haanenterprises.com/2013/04/host-your-own-dynamic-dns-using-php-and-cpanel-apis/
//
// usage:
// http://username:password@website.com/dyndns.php?hostname=remote&myip=192.168.1.1
//
// per the settings below, the above will update the IP remote.example.com to 192.168.1.1
// myip is not required, will default to the remote IP calling the script
//
// most dyndns clients will work with a custom url setting. you will likely need to only
// provide the subdomain and not the full address.
// (ie: with this script, hostname=remote   instead of hostname=remote.example.com
/***** Variables *****/
#The username and password used by the updater to send the request.
#HTTP Basic authentication
$php_auth_user='username';
$php_auth_pw='password';
#The url of the cpanel server
$dyndnsCpanel = 'https://example.com:2083';
#username and password used to login to cpanel
$dyndnsCpanelUser = 'username';
$dyndnsCpanelPass = 'password';
#the main domain name of the account on cpanel
$dyndnsDomain = 'example.com';
#the base domain of which the subdomain has a dynamic ip
$dyndnsRemoteHostDomain = '.example.com.';
// Plain text output
header('Content-type: text/plain');
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CPanel DynDyns"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die('Authentication Required.');
}
if(!($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']==$php_auth_user && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']==$php_auth_pw)) {
    sleep(10);
    die('Invalid Credentials');
}
// Make sure a host was specified
if (empty($_GET['hostname']))
    die('Must specify host');
// Use server value for IP if none was specified
$ip = $_GET['myip'];
if (empty($ip))
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
// Validate IP address
if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    die('Invalid IP address');

// Get and validate ttl
$ttl = $_GET['ttl'];
if (!is_numeric($ttl) || $ttl < 60)
    $ttl = 300;
// Create class object
$dyn = new DynDnsUpdater();
// Connection information
$dyn->setCpanelHost($dyndnsCpanel);
$dyn->setDomain($dyndnsDomain);
$dyn->setHostDomain($dyndnsRemoteHostDomain);
// Set username
$dyn->setCpanelUsername($dyndnsCpanelUser);
// Set password
$dyn->setCpanelPassword($dyndnsCpanelPass);
$dyn->updateHost($_GET['hostname'], $ip);
if ($dyn->apiCallTime > 0.0)
{
    echo "\nTotal cPanel API call time: {$dyn->apiCallTime} seconds\n";
}
// End of processing
exit;
/**********************************/
/*** Function definitions below ***/
/**********************************/
class DynDnsUpdater
{
    public $apiCallTime;
    private $curl;  
    private $cpanelHost;
    private $cpanelUsername;
    private $cpanelPassword;
    private $domain;
    private $hostDomain;
    /***** Constructor / Destructor *****/
    function __construct()
    {
        // Create curl object
        $this->curl = curl_init();      
        $curlDefaults = array(
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // Allow self-signed certs
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,    // Allow certs that do not match the hostname
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // Return contents
            );
        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $curlDefaults);

        $this->apiCallTime = 0.0;
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        // Release curl object
        curl_close($this->curl);
    }
    /***** Setters *****/
    function setCpanelHost($host)
    {
        $this->cpanelHost = $host;
    }

    function setCpanelUsername($username)
    {
        $this->cpanelUsername = $username;
    }

    function setCpanelPassword($password)
    {
        $this->cpanelPassword = $password;
    }

    function setDomain($domain)
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }
    function setHostDomain($domain)
    {
        $this->hostDomain = $domain;
    }
    /***** Public Functions *****/


    public function updateHost($host, $ip)
    {
        $hosts = $this->getHost($host);

        if ($hosts === false)
            return false;

        foreach ($hosts as $hostInfo)
        {
            if ($hostInfo['address'] == $ip)
            {
                echo "No update required: {$hostInfo['name']} ($ip)\n";
                return true;
            }

            $updateParams = array(
                'cpanel_jsonapi_module' => 'ZoneEdit',    
                'cpanel_jsonapi_func' => 'edit_zone_record',
                'domain' => $this->domain,
                'Line' => $hostInfo['Line'],
                'type' => $hostInfo['type'],
                'address' => $ip
            );



            $result = $this->cpanelRequest($updateParams);

            if ($result)
                echo "Update successful: {$hostInfo['name']} ($ip)\n";
            else
                echo "Update failed: {$hostInfo['name']}\n";
        }
    }

    /***** Private Functions *****/
    private function getHost($host)
    {
        $fetchzoneParams = array(
            'cpanel_jsonapi_module' => 'ZoneEdit',    
            'cpanel_jsonapi_func' => 'fetchzone_records',
            'domain' => $this->domain,
            'customonly' => 1
        );

        $result = $this->cpanelRequest($fetchzoneParams);
        if (empty($result['data']))
            return false;

        // Get the payload
        $zoneFile = $result['data'];

        $hosts = array();
        foreach ($zoneFile as $line)
        {
            if ( ($line['type'] == 'A') && 
                 ($host == DYNDNS_ALLHOSTS || (strcasecmp($line['name'], $host.$this->hostDomain) === 0)) )
            {   
                $hosts[] = $line;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($hosts))
            return $hosts;
        else
            echo "No hosts found\n";

        return false;
    }

    private function cpanelRequest($params)
    {
        if (empty($this->curl) || empty($params))
            return false;

        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->cpanelHost.'/json-api/cpanel?'.http_build_query($params));     
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($this->cpanelUsername.':'.$this->cpanelPassword)) );

        $result = curl_exec($this->curl);
        $this->apiCallTime += curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);
        $error = false;

        // Check for valid result
        if ($result === false)
        {
            echo curl_error($this->curl)."\n";

            // If curl didn't return anything, there's nothing else to check
            return false;
        }

        // Check for error code
        if (curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != '200')
        {
            $err = curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            echo "Error $err\n";
            $error = true;
        }

        // Attempt to process result
        $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);

        if (empty($jsonResult))
        {
            echo "Invalid JSON: \n".$result."\n";
            return false;
        }
        // Check for cpanelresult object
        if (isset($jsonResult['cpanelresult']))
        {
            $jsonResult = $jsonResult['cpanelresult'];
        }
        else
        {
            $error = true;
        }

        // Check for cpanel error
        if (isset($jsonResult['error']))
        {
            echo $jsonResult['error']."\n";
            $error = true;
        }

        if ($error)
        {
            // No sense going past here... no more information to get
            return false;
        }
        return $jsonResult;
    }
}
?>
```

> -->  linha: 199 No hosts found
>
> --> Total cPanel API call time: 0.406303 seconds

Alguém já usou ele e pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1):

"*No hosts found*" significa que o script não encontrou no domínio indicado pela variável `$dyndnsRemoteHostDomain` o host que você indicou na linha de comando.

Se você rodar o script com o seguinte URL:

```
http://username:password@website.com/dyndns.php?hostname=remote
```

O host *remote.website.com* precisa já existir. O script não o cria por você.

> OBS.: Estou considerando que obviamente você não está usando "esse" script, mas uma versão particular dele. Sem seus dados particulares "esse" script não funciona.

Comment: @chun, tenho sérias objeções à sua edição do meu texto. Em primeiro lugar, você alterou completamente o sentido do que eu disse no primeiro parágrafo. O que eu escrevi está certo. Sua edição está errada.

Comment: Obrigado pela chamada de atenção Jefferson. Sem problema, você sempre pode reverter a edição para como ela estava antigamente [aqui neste link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/99572/revisions), faça scroll para baixo até à sua versão e clique no link **reverter**. Se depois quiser formatar a pergunta à sua maneira, dê uma olhada aqui nestas páginas para lhe ajudar com a formatação da sua publicação: [Formatando](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) e também [Ajuda no Markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Peço desculpa por qualquer mal-entendimento e boa continuação.

Comment: Já reverti e acrescentei formatação. Obrigado.

Comment: Outro motivo para o script não encontrar o host é você deixar de colocar o "." inicial no valor da variável _$dyndnsRemoteHostDomain_. Aquilo não é erro de digitação. Acho que o script até poderia adicionar isso automaticamente por você, mas não sei qual a intenção do autor para requerer isso no valor da variável.

Comment: Tinha dado uma pausa nesse código para fazer outro vou testar novamente visando essas observações. Obrigado

Comment: Eu testei esse código recentemente e notei que **ambos** os pontos (inicial e final) no conteúdo da variável _$dyndnsRemoteHostDomain_  precisam existir. Por exemplo: _.teste.com.br._